# Wrap TextArea default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Form TextArea with a default value that is unfortunately sometimes quite big. How can I make it so that the form is expanded to the size of the text? Right now, my form input `ADI` is truncated so I can't see all of the text.

```
            <div style={{width: '50rem', margin: '1rem', overflow: 'auto'}}>
                <Header as='h2' textAlign='center' style={styles.mainHeader}>CMS View</Header>

                <Segment raised className='magentaSegment'>

                    <Form style={{paddingBottom: '2.5em'}} error={this.props.networksHasErrored}>
                        <Form.Group widths='equal'>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.TextArea fluid label='ADI' value = {cmsObj.ADI}  style={styles.normalColor} />

                    </Form>
                </Segment>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rows, cols and wrap properties of textarea. You can set fix values for rows and columns and then if the text is still bigger than given rows and cols combination then automated scrollbar will appear.

If you want your texarea to grow depend on text and dont want scroll bar then you have to dynamically set rows by calculating total no of characters in text.

```
function calculateRows(text){
  if(!text)
  return 1;

  return  Math.ceil(text.length/10);
}
const rows = calculateRows(text)
<textarea id="story" name="story" rows={rows} cols="10">
```